# Writing memory of the traced process.

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am playing around with ptrace in linux. I am trying to write the memory  of the traced process using /proc/pid/mem interface.

the function I ma using for accomplish this task is :

```
void write_proc(pid_t child, unsigned long int addr) {

  char mem_file_name[100];
  char buf[10]="hope";
  int mem_fd;


  memset( (void*)mem_file_name, 0, 100);
  memset( (void *)buf, 0, 10);

  sprintf(mem_file_name, "/proc/%d/mem", child);
  mem_fd = open(mem_file_name, O_RDONLY);
  lseek(mem_fd, addr , SEEK_SET);

  if (write(mem_fd, buf, 5) < 0 )
    perror("Writing");

  return;

}
```

But I always get the error : Writing: Bad file descriptor.

Is it possible to write the traced process using this method?

Comment: Why are you asking? What is your use case of `ptrace` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening the file in read-only mode (`O_RDONLY`). I'd suggest trying again with `O_RDWR` instead:

```
  mem_fd = open(mem_file_name, O_RDWR);
```

However, from `man proc` it's not clear this will work:

> ```
>    /proc/[pid]/mem
>           This  file can be used to access the pages of a process's memory
>           through open(2), read(2), and lseek(2).
> ```

EDIT:

I was curious too, so I put together this example using just `ptrace()` directly:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SHOW(call) ({ int _ret = (int)(call); printf("%s -> %d\n", #call, _ret); if (_ret < 0) { perror(NULL); }})

char changeme[] = "This is  a test";

int main (void)
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  int ret;
  int i;
  union {
    char cdata[8];
    int64_t data;
  } u = { "Hijacked" };

  switch (pid) {
  case 0: /* child */
    sleep(1);
    printf("Message: %s\n", changeme);
    exit(0);

  case -1:
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
    break;

  default: /* parent */
    SHOW(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0));
    SHOW(ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, changeme, u.data));
    SHOW(ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0));
    wait(NULL);
    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it should work... perhaps `mmap`-ing that file coul be better... However, `O_RDWR` is required at `open` time (but might not work for `/proc/*pid/mem` ... I don't know...)

Comment: You are right. The only problem was the I was opening the file on read only mode. Copy and paste is the source of most bugs... AHAHAH! 
Thanks!! 
However, PTRACE_POKEDATA is not a goo solution you can write only 4 (x32) or 8 (x64) per time. 
The best solution for this problem is : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html

Answer (score 2):

[ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) is a very arcane syscall, only used by debuggers and the like.

For sure, the documented `PTRACE_POKEDATA` request to `ptrace`  should work (when the traced process is stopped) and gives you the ability to write into the memory of the traced process. I don't know if writing (or `mmap`-ing) to `/proc/$pid/mem` should work or not.

Googling on `linux write /proc /mem` give me notably [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/432347/) which suggests that  `/proc/$pid/mem` was designed to be read-only, but might have been made writable in recent kernels. But recent [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.8.4) from kernel source tree don't say much.

I would be cautious about writing on `/proc/$pid/mem`; if it works (and it might not) it probably is very kernel version specific.

<sub>Perhaps `mmap`-ing some segments of that `/proc/$pid/mem` file does work (but I don't know). Have you tried that?</sub>

In contrast, `PTRACE_POKEDATA` should work (it has existed in SunOS and many other Unixes before Linux existed). Of course, it is fairly slow.

Comment: Ptrace_POKEDATA offers a low bandwidth to transfer data. You are right when you say to use this method carefully... There is a bit of confusion with this approach because when the possibility to write the  memmory of the traced process a bug has been introduced in the kernel.. For more info check out this link  : 
http://lwn.net/Articles/476947/